# Feynman rule 4-point vertex WW -> ZZ

Tags: quantum-field-theory, yang-mills, feynman-diagrams

I am looking for the Feynman rule of the 4-point gauge boson interaction of W+ W- -> Z Z. I am guessing it looks like the Yang Mills 4-point vertex for gluons, but with helicity included.

Equation 8.81 in my professor's [lecture notes](http://www.hef.ru.nl/~kleiss/qft.pdf) seems to imply polarization, or am I misinterpreting?

Comment: have a look at http://arxiv.org/ftp/hep-ph/papers/0306/0306160.pdf

Comment: unfortunately the article does not give an expression for the vertex. I need that in order to calculate the amplitude.

Comment: Always better to link to the abstract page http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0306160 both so that readers can *read* the abstract before deciding to download the paper and because that way they can look at the [refers to](http://arxiv.org/refs/hep-ph/0306160) and [cited by](http://arxiv.org/cits/hep-ph/0306160) links.

Comment: this has a lagrangian and a table with couplings: http://acfahep.kek.jp/acfareport/node182.html . I found it by google, asking for "WW ZZ quartic coupling standard model"

Comment: There isn't any helicity-dependence in the coupling of gauge bosons; only fermions are chiral in the electroweak theory. Up to different coupling constants and structure constants, the WWZZ vertex is identical to that of 4 gluons and may be found in any textbook such as Peskin and Schroeder.

Comment: Equation 8.81 in my professor's lecture notes seems to imply chirality: http://www.hef.ru.nl/~kleiss/qft.pdf, or am I misinterpreting?

Comment: It would be good to edit things like that into the question, so that we know that you've already tried the obvious techniques and why they're not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the vertex $X$ has to be contracted with the particle polarizations in the following manner, is

$$X^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta} \epsilon_{1_\mu} \epsilon_{2_\nu} \epsilon_{3_\alpha} \epsilon_{4_\beta}$$
where

$$X^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta} = 2 g^{\mu \nu} g^{\alpha \beta} - g^{\mu \alpha} g^{\nu \beta} - g^{\mu \beta} g^{\nu \alpha}$$

This results in:

$$2(\epsilon_1 \cdot \epsilon_2) (\epsilon_3 \cdot \epsilon_4) - (\epsilon_1 \cdot \epsilon_3) (\epsilon_2 \cdot \epsilon_4) - (\epsilon_1 \cdot \epsilon_4) (\epsilon_2 \cdot \epsilon_3)$$